# An integer as a condition

Tags: python-3.3

been having some trouble with something that should work just fine.

Lets say

```
x = 5
if x == True:
    ...
```

the '...' will happen as the statement is correct.  Any variable evaluated as a condition is True unless empty or false. 
What I'm attempting is a while statement using this concept:

```
x=input("enter a number")

while x == True:
  ...
  ...
```

When run, it displays no errors but does not run the program. The shell refreshes to a new line and acts as though nothing happened. 
thank's ahead for the help.

Comment: What do you want to consider a "true" number?

Comment: any non zero number (supposedly) is considered True by python. At least, that's what my textbook claimed. In my particular case, any integer between 1 & 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 5
while x:
   ...
```

or

```
x = 5

if x:
```

Python apparently wants this in short hand.
"while x:" is effectively the same as "while x == true:"
this is likely to avoid seeing True as the value of x, not its condition.
Thanks for the help, sorry for the silly blunder.

This does work, and this is exactly what I was trying to do.

in contrast,

```
x=0
if x:
  ...
elif:
  ...
```

this will run the elif condition, not if. Because x = 0, and is therefore False.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the first example worked? I ran it and it didn't. If you just want the loop to always run, do a `while True:` or an `if True:`. A number is never "true". What you can do is this, which is like a `while True`:

```
x=input("enter a number")

while x == x:
...
...
```

Or this, which is just checking for one instance:

```
x=input("enter a number")

while x == 5:
...
...
```

Your example will never work because, I repeat, **a number is NEVER "True"**

Comment: Incorrect. Evaluated as a condition, any non zero number is considered True.